# Proper place to request an oAuth2 bearer token so it could be used by a registered HttpClient in a .NET Core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating a Client that needs to make call to an external API from an ASP.NET Core Blazor Server app. I am trying to figure out a clean way to follow this pattern and request a bearer token from an oAuth2 endpoint that needs to be used in all of the calls. I currently have the HttpClient setup in the following way:

In my **Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>(client => {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my-api/");
});
```

In **MyClient.cs**:

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
public MyClient(HttpClient httpClient) {
    _httpClient = httpClient;
}

public async Task<List<Project>?> GetProjectsAsync() {
    var projectResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync("Projects");
}
```

I would like to know what the recommended way to first make a call to an oAuth2 endpoint sending in a base64 secret. Receive a bearer token to be used in the header of all of the requests of MyClient makes to https://my-api/.

I found a good example here on how to prepare for a token request:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/729834/create-client-token-oauth2-question.html

I am just confused as to how to make it all flow with the .net core dependency injection. Should I be adding all of the code to request the token in my Program.cs and then when calling AddHttpClient add the token to the headers? Or should this logic be inside the MyClient.cs file?

Answer (score 1):

For adding the token to header for all requests from the httpClient you can implement an HttpMessageHandler like this:

```
public class HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler
   : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var authorizationHeader = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
                .Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader))
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new List<string>() { authorizationHeader });
            }

            var token = await GetToken();

            if (token != null)
            {
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

            return await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
                .GetTokenAsync(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        }
    }
```

and then add this handler when defining the httpClient at program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TInterface, TImplementation>()
.AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>();
```

I have this code [here](https://github.com/mzand111/MZBase/tree/master/MZBase.Microservices) with some other classes to make the life with httpClient a little bit easier. Also available as [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MZBase.Microservices/)